# How to enable experimentalDecorators in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-decorators

This question is not a duplicate of those questions which ask how to suppress a similar warning issued by the code editors such as VSCode.

My problem is for the Tsc command line compiler warning:

> greet.ts:7:7 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a
>   feature th at is subject to change in a future release. Set the
>   'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

Here is my code:

```
function doMore(target) {
    target.doMore = true;
}

@doMore
class Test {
    do() {
        console.log('done');
    }
}  


var t = new Test();
t.do();
console.log(t.doMore);
```

I created the following tsconfig.json in the root directory:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

But `tsc` still complains.

Comment: works fine here. Are you sure it's picking the correct tsconfig?

Comment: @georg The tsconfig.json resides in the same folder as the greet.ts - which is my only source file. My VSCode suppressed the same warning after I created the tsconfig.json

Comment: If you invoke it like `tsc greet.ts` it doesn't use tsconfig...

Comment: Please tell me how to make tsc use the tsconfig.json

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html . Basically, add "greet.ts" to `files` in tsconfig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tsc` compiler ignores the tsconfig.js when the input files are specified in the command line:

The `tsc greet.ts1 will simply ignore the tsconfig.json file - thus no compiler options specified in the file will be effective.

The tsconfig.json file should be included with the source file paths and the `tsc` compiler should be called without specifying the source files in order to include the tsconfig.js file in the compilation.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "ES5"
    },

    "files": [
        "greet.ts"
    ]
}
```